# Match digits with optional commas and dot

Tags: java, regex

What is the regex to match one or more digits with commas for thousands separator, followed by an optional dot and decimals, as in:

**Must match**

```
1 
12
123,123
123,123.000
123.123
```

But not,

```
123.123,123
```

Comment: I don't see a clear pattern here.. I don't think regex will be the right way to go. There will be too many - "what -ifs?" .

Comment: still i cant get your point.

Comment: Tried to clarify your question and its title. Does it still say what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're looking for something like this (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/pS3mN2)):

```
^\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{3})?$
```

1. This allows for multiple comma-separated thousands groups as in 12,345,678.000
2. Please note that there are three digits after the period (or none). If instead you'd like to allow one or more, change the `\d{3}` to a `\d+`

**Explain Regex**

```
^                        # the beginning of the string
\d+                      # digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                         # the most amount possible))
(?:                      # group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                         # (matching the most amount possible)):
  ,                      #   ','
  \d{3}                  #   digits (0-9) (3 times)
)*                       # end of grouping
(?:                      # group, but do not capture (optional
                         # (matching the most amount possible)):
  \.                     #   '.'
  \d{3}                  #   digits (0-9) (3 times)
)?                       # end of grouping
$                        # before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         # string
```

Comment: I was writing about the same thing, but with `sed` syntax. I might as well add it here now, hope you don't mind: `sed -n '/^[0-9]\+\(,[0-9]\{3\}\)*\(.[0-9]\{3\}\)\?$/p' file_to_parse`

Comment: @Qeole not at all, join the party, the question may soon be deleted. :) Btw I haven't used sed, you have to escape all the special regex characters as you're doing there with `\{` etc?

Comment: Not all of them. `.,*,^,$,[,]` for example are considered as special chars if unescaped, whereas `+,?,{,}` for instance are normal characters by default. It does result sometimes in pretty hard-to-read lines.